# How to make text show up - new page template

Tags: page-template

I created a Page Template following these instructions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

When I create some text in a test page and apply the template I created using the instructions at that link, the text I create doesn't show up when I go 'view page'.

What code do I need to add to the template so that text shows up?

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: what is the exact code of your page template?

Comment: If you view source, can you see the text in the HTML? it may be a styling issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template must have the [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) function called within the Wordpress loop to show up the text you've entered while creating new post.

You might have missed the `the_content()` function in your custom template, that function retrieves and show the content of your page.

#### Here is sample usage

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); /*This code prints the content*/ ?> 
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```